# How to provision a File with a DateTime Property set on [today]?

Tags: date-time, provisioning

I'm able to provision a file in a document library via a module like this :

```
<Module Name="myModuleName" SetupPath="SiteTemplates\BLANKINTERNET" Url="Pages" >
  <File Path="default.aspx" Url="default.aspx" Type="GhostableInLibrary" IgnoreIfAlreadyExists="TRUE">
    <Property Name="Title" Value="My title" />
    <Property Name="ContentType" Value="My custom page type" />
    <Property Name="PublishingPageLayout" Value="~SiteCollection/_catalogs/masterpage/customLayout.aspx, My custom page Layout" />
  </File>
</Module>
```

My custom page type is using a field with a <Default/> value set on [today] but it seems that this property is used only when I create a page from the UI.
Now I'd like to set this [today] value by provisioning the file.

I tried this but it doesn't work :

```
<Module Name="myModuleName" SetupPath="SiteTemplates\BLANKINTERNET" Url="Pages" >
  <File Path="default.aspx" Url="default.aspx" Type="GhostableInLibrary" IgnoreIfAlreadyExists="TRUE">
    <Property Name="Title" Value="My title" />
    <Property Name="ContentType" Value="My custom page type" />
    <Property Name="PublishingPageLayout" Value="~SiteCollection/_catalogs/masterpage/customLayout.aspx, My custom page Layout" />
    <Property Name="MyDate" Type="DateTime" Value="[today]" />
  </File>
</Module>
```

Any suggestions on how to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

I am no developer so cannot help with the code, but surely when you add the document to the library the Created date column will automatically be Today?

Comment: Hi, yes it is.

The column is also provisioned by a custom feature with this XML : <Default>[Today]</Default>